# Can Hilbert projection theorem be proved without AC?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, axiom-of-choice, projection

**Hilbert projection theorem** For every vector $x$ in a Hilbert space $H$ and every closed vector subspace $C$, there exists a unique vector $m\in C$ such that $x−m$ is orthogonal to $C$.

All proofs of this theorem that I know of use the axiom of countable choice.

Can Hilbert projection theorem be proved without AC or its weak form?

There is a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/783760) with a similar title, but its answer does not answer this question.

Comment: How is the linked question's answer not an answer to this question?

Comment: @JamesHanson It uses CC and the definition of completeness is not standard.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.09602) is more to your liking then.  In particular, Theorem 1.0.2 and Theorem 2.0.4.

Comment: I don't know if it's 'standard' per se, but the Cauchy filter definition of completeness is really the only correct definition if you're not going to use choice. Also that answer does not use CC for showing that orthogonal projections exist in (Cauchy filter complete) Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @JamesHanson I know we can prove various theorems without AC if we assume the Hilbert space is separable. Is it better to change the definition of completeness?

Comment: To add to what @user10354138 wrote, I have just submitted the final version to the arXiv. So, there's that.

Comment: The point of this definition is that it is the most 'complete' metric space the original metric space embeds into densely. (It's actually characterized by a universal property, namely that any isometric image of the space is topologically closed). For Hilbert spaces in particular, it's also equivalent to the double dual of the space. It depends on what else you want to prove, but one thing it lets you do immediately is form orthogonal projections.

Comment: @JamesHanson That sounds interesting. Is the Cauchy filter definition of completeness equivalent to σ-completeness (definition 1.0.1., theorem1.0.2. in the paper linked in @user10354138’s comment)? Is there a textbook or reference on Hilbert space theory based on the Cauchy filter definition?

Comment: @BonBon Yes, they are equivalent. I do not know of a textbook because my impression is that there aren't really any functional analysis texts that avoid countable choice. That said, as I discuss in [one of my MO answers here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455834/proof-of-global-peano-existence-theorem-in-zf/455875#455875) you actually can transfer a lot of ordinary theorems from ZFC to ZF automatically.

Comment: @BonBon Oh but that said, there's a fair amount of literature on constructive analysis (even without countable choice) and in that context they would definitely use the Cauchy filter definition. I don't know any good references for it though.

Comment: @BonBon Note that uniformly complete (definition 1.0.1(iv)) is in terms of Cauchy nets, i.e., basically the same as Cauchy filters except using the dual notion of nets instead of filters.